# Difference in opening a website in a machine using ip address and localhost?

Tags: security, internet-explorer

I have a website configured in my IIS.

In the browser(Internet Explorer) when I open(*in the same machine where is the website hosted in IIS*) it by giving url with localhost it opens correctly, but when I give the IP address it displays me a pop up

> "Content from the website listed below is being blocked by the
>   internet explorer Enhanced security Configuration"

What is the logical difference when a website is being opened by giving localhost and when a user gives a IP?

Comment: localhost accesses your inner network. Unless you type the equivalent to localhost in IP (`127.0.0.1`), any other address you use to access your site will be treated by IE as coming from the Internet. At that point, the safety settings you set up apply.

Answer (score 3):

IE sees the world as [zones](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174360), including "The Internet", "Local Intranet", "Trusted Sites", and "Restricted Sites", and each zone has its own security configuration.

'localhost' is a member of the "Local Intranet" zone, as should be your local IP address or fqdn within your LAN, but unfourtunately due to a [bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303650), IE treats any url with a dot '.' in it as in the 'Internet' zone instead which has much more stringent security settings.

Per the bug details, you can work around the issue, by manually adding the url you are using to the Local Intranet zone by selecting the zone -> Advanced.